# quarkus-maven-plugin reports: [WARNING] [io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanArchives] Failed to index

Tags: java, quarkus, jandex

I'm trying to setup a legacy (jboss-eap) project on quarkus

I cannot find a maven dependency to CXF but I know its a "provided" dependency in one of my common-libs since CXF is offered by JBOSS.

Now I run into a warning during build:

```
INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.10.5.Final:build (default) @ gmw_rest_dispatch ---
[INFO] [org.jboss.threads] JBoss Threads version 3.1.1.Final
[INFO] [org.hibernate.Version] HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.26.Final
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanArchives] Failed to index org.apache.cxf.phase.AbstractPhaseInterceptor: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader
[INFO] [io.quarkus.arc.processor.IndexClassLookupUtils] Class for name: org.apache.cxf.phase.AbstractPhaseInterceptor was not found in Jandex index. Please ensure the class is part of the index.
[WARNING] [io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanArchives] Failed to index org.apache.cxf.feature.AbstractFeature: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader
[INFO] [io.quarkus.arc.processor.IndexClassLookupUtils] Class for name: org.apache.cxf.feature.AbstractFeature was not found in Jandex index. Please ensure the class is part of the index.
```

I want my build as clean as possible. So I'd like to get rid of this warning. How can I achieve that?

As a side-note: I can't view what jandex writes to its jandex.idx. So I've no means to debug. Note that the mentioned (org.apache.xf.phase.AbstractPhaseIntercepter and org.apache.cxf.feature.AbstractFeature) classes are also not annotations (AFAIK).